# Mootools destroys my globals!!! Google Maps + Mootools

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mootools, global

Im using Mootools for a few things like bumpboxes and stuff in a Google Maps application. Everything was working 100%, before I added the Mootools script, it doesn't matter if I add the script before or after I declare my globals, Mootools kills them...take a look at a snippet

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="mootools.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="bumpbox.js"></script>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var currentBounds;
    var currentMarker = null;
    var currentInfo = null;
    var markersArrayProps = [];
    var markersArrayAreas = [];
</script>
```

There's a lot more...but this just shows whats going on, everything works fine if I remove the line calling `mootools.js`. Basically `markersArrayProps` is populated like this during an XMLHTTPRequest:

```
markersArrayAreas.push(marker);
```

Then there is a event listener for the map being `idle` which does some calculations to see if it should drop the area markers, and load property markers based upon the bounds of the map. No need to get into the details, but whenever this `idle` function is called, and I loop through the array like this:

```
function clearAreaOverlays() {
  if (markersArrayAreas) {
    for (i in markersArrayAreas) {
      markersArrayAreas[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
}
```

It returns `markersArrayAreas[i].setMap()` is not a function. Only with the mootools script included in the page, if I remove mootools, everything works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks for everyones input, and a special thanks to Jason for pointing out about the mootools array prototype....using mootools `.each` function

```
    markersArrayAreas.each (function (item){
        item.setMap(null);
    });
```

Comment: The each function uses MooTools forEach, which iterates through the array in exactly the same way as I proposed above.

Comment: Ah, except it checks that the value is not undefined for each index. So the problem is that a new function in MooTools was modifying your array such that an element became undefined. In general, you should always check for the existence of an object after looking it up, before trying to call a function or access a property of it.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to fix this is to rewrite your loop using the pattern:

```
for(var i=0,l=markersArrayAreas.length, i<l, i++) { if(i in markersArrayAreas) { ... } }
```

It looks like you're using markersArrayAreas as a standard integer-indexed array. So, you shouldn't use the `(for i in array)` pattern to iterate through it. First of all, it's much less efficient than using an index-based counting loop.

But furthermore, this pattern iterates through all members of an object. In your case, MooTools has extended the Array prototype with some more custom functions, so whenever you create an array, there are now additional properties in the object besides the numbered array values. If you print the value of `i` you should see that it's no longer just numbers.

You could get around this by checking to see if each property name refers to a property that *wasn't* inherited from the prototype using the `hasOwnProperty` function, but again, this would be much less efficient than.

For a quick benchmark that shows the relative performance of these different looping constructs, see here: http://jsperf.com/for-in-test

Comment: +1 `for ( i in array )` seems to usually work, untill the `Array.prototype` gets enriched with extra methods, which is the case in MooTools. But the loop pattern used by OP is still a bad way to loop over an enumerable.

Comment: That didn't work, still markersArrayArea[i].setMap is not a function...I wish it was that simple

Comment: Have you tried inspecting what the value of markersArrayArea[i] *is*? Is it null, or is it undefined, or is it some unexpected object?

Comment: unexpected object...it was one of those mootools properties throwing it off. This maps app is being built into a pre-existing site that uses mootools, so I wasn't familiar with the in's and out's...thanks for the input `markersArrayAreas.each` fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You could namespace those global variables. It would require a bit of reworking, but it's guaranteed to keep your stuff safe from other scripts:

```
var my_globals_with_a_very_unique_name_mf = {
    // redeclare all your variables in here
}
```

Then, whenever you refer to those variables, just go into the object:

```
my_globals_with_a_very_unique_name_mf.markersArrayProps
```

Comment: Namespacing the variables instead of throwing them in the global namespace (or better yet, using the module pattern) is also a good suggestion that the OP should follow. However, it's not the cause of the issue in question here.

Comment: Yea, that didn't work either...wish it would have...any other suggestions?